# Make an image a button in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am developing a GUI in MATLAB and am trying to allow a user to click on an image in order to enable a push button, and then this image will change like a toggle button, but I am struggling and am hoping for some advice, how can this be done?

I've seen that you can put icons on push buttons in MATLAB and that you can extract the position of the mouse on a click, but I can't figure out if these help my situation. I don't want to put the icon on the button because a) its not the look I am going for and b) I want to be able to change the image depending on the state of the button.

Thanks

Comment: Clarification: Do you want the image to act as a pushbutton? Or do you want the image to change into another image, when pushed, and then also create/display a separate pushbutton?

Comment: I want to do the latter, where the image changes and also controls a separate pushbutton.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key to your problem is `ButtonDownFcn`. You need to set your images `ButtonDownFcn` to reference come function which both changes the image displayed, and does whatever else you need it to do. So, for example, say your create you image in you operating function like so:

```
...
yourImHandle = image(someImage);
set(yourImHandle, 'ButtonDownFcn', {@yourPushbuttonFcn, yourImHandle, otherVar});
...
```

Where `yourPushbuttonFcn` is defined elsewhere as:

```
function yourPushbuttonFcn(yourImageHandle, otherVar)
    set(yourImageHandle, 'CData', someOtherImage);
    otherVar=otherVar+1;                              %# Do other things.
end
```

This will change the image for you, and sets up the platform for you to do other, more complicated things inside the push button function. Let me know if you have any questions.

Good Luck.

Comment: Thanks, that is clear apart from one thing. I've only ever used axes and imshow to display an image, how do I display one using image(..)?

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out. In case anyone has the same question, I wrote this:
`variable = imread('imagename.jpg');
handles.myaxes = image(variable); ` then followed Fletch's code